# Graph edge attributes

Tags: python, networkx

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5])
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,1)])
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {(1, 2): {"cost": 2.0}})
cost = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "cost")
cost[(1, 2)]
# pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'cost')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Need Help!! New to Networkx! I created 5 nodes and 5 edges. I created an edge attribute "cost" and assigned cost = 2 between edge 1,2. I would like to visualize this cost attribute on graph. Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 0):

using [`nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html) function you can plot edge labels:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5])
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,1)])
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {(1, 2): {"cost": 2.0}})
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "cost")

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels)
```

[image: Networkx plot with edge label]

Comment: If you use the `pos` also in the `nx.draw` the result should look even better.